# Find records that start with specific digits MongoDB from other collection

Tags: database, mongodb, collections

I have two collections that look like this:

**Ship_Data**

```
 {
    _id: ObjectId("63d19d7a1991a09011aa35ef"),
    sourcemmsi: 228051000,
    navigationalstatus: 0,
    course: {
      rateofturn: -127,
      speedoverground: 0,
      courseoverground: 291.5,
      trueheading: 511
    },
    coordinates: {
      longitude: -4.4850965,
      latitude: 48.38132,
      timestamp: 1443650424
    }
  }
```

**SourceMMSI**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("63d19f671991a09011e4eba4"),
    mmsi_code: 228,
    country: 'France'
  }
```

The first one (Ship_Data) has informations about specific ships while the second one (SourceMMSI) shows what the first digits of source mmsi code represent. For example in our case since the sourcemmsi field in Ship_Data start with *228*, based on the second collection, the ship might be from France.

What I want to accomplish is to create a query using those two collection and returns records based on the first three digits from the sourcemmsi field. Is there any way I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the code into strings by `$toString` (`sourcemmsi` need an extra conversion to Long first before converting to string). Then, use `$indexOfCP` to perform substring check and see whether the index is 0. (i.e. at start of the `sourcemmsi`).

```js
db.SourceMMSI.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Ship_Data",
      "let": {
        code: {
          "$toString": "$mmsi_code"
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                0,
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    {
                      $toString: {
                        $toLong: "$sourcemmsi"
                      }
                    },
                    "$$code"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "shipDataLookup"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nTQUjOnpJ6u)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used it and it returns the records I want. However is there any way I can replace the $lookup operator with something else? (since lookup is slow operation)

Comment: @CostasGinos You are putting the records in seperate collections. `$lookup` is the canonical way to link up 2 collections in MongoDB. You may consider refactoring your schema if you want to avoid `$lookup`